# Xamarin Access View.IsVisible From Another Module

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

C#, Xamarin.Forms.  Basically I'm trying to access an object's property from another module.  I did search StackOverflow, but couldn't find anything like this specific question.

Specifically: I'm trying to determine if a view inside a page is visible.  This is accessed from a global module that is not the same scope as the page object.

The top level object is "MainPage", and the Views within it are timerAndClock, taktTime, etc.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:D6500"
             xmlns:CustomViews="clr-namespace:D6500.Views"
             x:Class="D6500.MainPage">
    <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CustomViews:TimerAndClock x:Name="timerAndClock" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" PropertyChanged="TabbedPage_PropertyChanged" Opacity="1" />
        <CustomViews:TaktTime x:Name="taktTime" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="False" PropertyChanged="TabbedPage_PropertyChanged" Opacity="0"  />
        <CustomViews:Day_Counter x:Name="day_Counter" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="False" PropertyChanged="TabbedPage_PropertyChanged" Opacity="0"  />
        <CustomViews:mainDisplayList x:Name="mainDisplayList" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="False" PropertyChanged="TabbedPage_PropertyChanged" Opacity="0"  />
        <CustomViews:BottomNavigationBar x:Name="BottomNavigationbar" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I'm trying to access from a global module.  Here is the gist:

```
namespace D6500
{
public static class Config
    {
        public static async void TimerGSS_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(MainPage.timerAndClock.IsVisible)
            {
                //Do view specific stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is `'MainPage.timerAndClock' is not accessible due to its protection level`.  While I understand the variable is not public, I don't know how to change that, as it's created within the XAML for MainPage (see above).  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out my initial access issue, but here is how I solved the problem.

1. I moved the function TimerGSS_Elapsed() from the Config Module to MainPage, where it is a local context.
2. That function could no longer be static, which broke references in the sub-views.
3. I had to find a reference to the instance of MainPage.  Below is how I reference from inside TaktTime to MainPage.

   ```
   namespace D6500.Views
   {
       [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
       public partial class TaktTime : ContentView

       private void OnAppearing()
       {
           ....
           //Start timer after we have finished reading and writing to the display
           var NP = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
           var mp = NP.RootPage as D6500.MainPage;
           mp.timerGSS.Start();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

create a public helper method or property

```
public bool IsTimerViewVisible {
  get {
    return timerAndClock.IsVisible;
  }
}
```

Comment: S.O. didn't notify me about your response :(  That might work if I placed the function inside MainPage.  Even then I will need a reference to MainPage, which I did figure out, and will include in my solution below.